# HP ALM 12.50 Rest API Sign-in returns forbidden using Postman

Tags: rest, postman, hp-alm

I'm trying to sign in to HP ALM via its Rest API using Postman.

Following the reference for 12.50 version (https://almsyngenta.saas.hpe.com/qcbin/Help/doc_library/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#sign_in.htm), I'm sending a POST request to:

```
https://almalm1250saastrial.saas.hpe.com/qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in
```

Using the header:

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64-encoded username:password>
```

And the response i'm getting is:

```
HTTP Error 403 - Problem accessing /qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in. Reason: Forbidden
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my request? I'm just following the reference I linked above.

NOTE: The account used for the sign in process is a trial account and I can sign in with any problems from a browser.

Comment: I've validated using my credentials and it is working fine, Check for the complete URL. A screenshot of the POSTMAN tool probably ?

Comment: Thanks for checking it, here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/dvE9N8S

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, This looks to be an issue with the backend. I tried to hit the URL from your image and I got the same error ( 403 )

[image]

whereas on the other hand, if the URL was to accept API requests and if the user details are incorrect the below would be the response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is my analysis on REST API call to ALM . Go through [here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/uipath-with-alm/145840/2)

You can request for ALM database API and use the same API to report UiPath results. It will go directly into ALM server. But you need to work with ALM server admins in your organization for this.

You need ALM server side customization is required.Please find out ALM APIs which will accept data from other sources. use those APIs in UiPath and you can integrate both.

HP ALM Supports Rest API’s So you can also give it a try with HTTP REquest Activity.

From https://{host}/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate

1. In Postman enter the URL
2. Add below Headers(for instance, using JSON): `"Key":"Content-Type", "Value":"application/json"`
3. Select the desired method i.e. POST
4. Click on Body, choose raw and provide following data in body of request

```
{
"username": "value",
"password": "value"
}
```

5. Click Send button to hit the API.
6. Make sure status returns 200/OK response
7. If there is a functionality for token, the response body must contains Token

Hope my answers will helps you.

See also the following references:

- [AMD help](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST/Default.htm#REST_API/fields_clause.htm%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CRequest%2520Clauses%7C_____1)
- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mm2xgMoUSHM)
- [Bolte 1](https://consulting-bolte.de/index.php/22-tech-blog/hp-alm/hp-alm-rest-api/114-connect-to-hp-alm-via-browser-using-rest-api)
- [Bolte 2](https://consulting-bolte.de/index.php/tech-blog/hp-alm/hp-alm-rest-api)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-test-login-rest-API-service-using-postman)
- [Host](https://%7Bhost%7D/qcbin/rest/domains/%7Bdomain%7D/projects/%7Bproject%7D/defects)
- [Test Guild](https://testguild.com/alm-rest-api/)
- [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ov6v.jpg)
- [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html)